# DRF Get likes and dislikes grouped by day

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I have a models named Post and Like. How can i get json with ount of likes and dislikes grouped by date (date field in Like model)?

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """Post model"""
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Like(models.Model):
    """Like model"""
    LIKE = (
        ('like', 'like'),
        ('dislike', 'dislike')
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    like = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=LIKE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my **serializers.py:**

```
class AnaliticsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Like analitic"""

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my **vievs.py:**

```
class AnaliticView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnaliticsSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['date']
```

**result what i want**

```
[
  {
    "date": "2020-11-14",
    "total_likes": 25,
    "total_dislikes": 17
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-11-15",
    "total_likes": 38,
    "total_dislikes": 8
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-11-18",
    "total_likes": 11,
    "total_dislikes": 0
  }
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this using DRF's generic views and serializers alone. Their main use case is CRUD operations on the Django ORM.

You might as well just write an `APIView` with a `get` method that returns the appropriate JSON.

Comment: I can't user something like SerializerMethodField and get_likes_count method in my Serializer ?

Comment: You probably could, though I can't imagine how. The`ModelSerializer` class is designed to serialise model instances. What you'd be serializing, although not directly,  is ModelSerizlizer querysets filtered by `created_at`.

Comment: You could write a class that represents likes analytics ( `LikesAnalytics`) over a certain time period, and pas a list of those to a serializer, though I've never attempted anything like that.

Comment: The seriliser would be a bit pointless because it would be your code, not a HTTP client that is generating the values. Why validate your own values? That's what automated tests are for.

Comment: so i need to create a get method in APIView what return data what i want, and pass to serializer ?

Comment: Just to be clear I don't think the serialiser is necesscary in this case. I'm going to answer this with my idea of minimal working implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I want to see how to implement this in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of one basic approach to this. It should give you the idea.

The analytics code shouldn't really be in the view. Also, some of the grouping and counting might be offloaded to the database, using advanced ORM querying like [this](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/02/24/django-aggregation-group-by-day.html).

`views.py`

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from likes.filters import DateRangeFilterSet
from likes.models import Like


class AnaliticView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = DateRangeFilterSet

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filtered_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

        # Queryset needs to be ordered by date for groupby to work correctly
        ordered_queryset = filtered_queryset.order_by('date')
        likes_by_date = groupby(ordered_queryset,
                                lambda like: like.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

        analytics = []
        for date, likes in likes_by_date:
            count = Counter(like.like for like in likes)
            analytics.append(
                {
                    'date': date,
                    'total_likes': count['like'],
                    'total_dislikes': count['dislike'],

                }
            )

        return Response(analytics)
```

Like I said in the comments, it would be possible to create a lightweight class with attributes for date and the two totals, and pass a list of instances of that to a serializer to get the response data. In my opinion, that's overkill as you can just build a dictionary that is easily serialised into JSON.

**Update:**

I've switched to a `GenericAPIView`, which is a superclass of `ListAPIView`, because it supports filter backends. I have added a `FilterSet` that filters by `date_from` and `date_to`:

`filters.py`

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from likes import models


class DateRangeFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    date_from = filters.DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_to = filters.DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Like
        fields = ('date_from', 'date_to')
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. Another question. I can't user ApiView with django-filter ?

Comment: Do you mean the `django-filter` package? You could just call the filter class in the `get` function like they do in the documentation: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#the-view

If you mean DRF's `DjangoFilterBackend`, you'd have to re-write the view as a `ListAPIView` like you suggested in the question. I can re-write my answer if this is the case.

Comment: If it doesn't bother you. I would like to be able to filter data by date range. For example analitics/?date_from=2020-11-14&date_to=2020-11-17

Comment: Okay Nick, I've updated the answer using `django-filter`. If you want any more features, I'm afraid you're going to have to hire me as a developer XD

Comment: Thank you so much. I just recently took up DRF and you helped me a lot to advance))

Comment: Thanks bro @SimonCrowe. Wanna ask, do i need to create a url for these or not? If No, then how can I pass these in front-end.